# Dynamically Removing string with regex python

Tags: python, regex, string

I am currently having trouble removing the end of strings using regex. I have tried using `.partition` with unsuccessful results. I am now trying to use regex unsuccessfully. All the strings follow the format of `some random words **X*.* Some more words`. Where `*` is a digit and `X` is a literal X. For Example `21X2.5`. Everything after this dynamic string should be removed. I am trying to use `re.sub('\d\d\X\d.\d', string)`. Can someone point me in the right direction with regex and how to split the string?

The expected output should read:
`some random words 21X2.5`

Thanks!

Comment: what is your expected output? Do you want to replace `21X2.5` with something else? or remove end of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is not correct. The biggest problem is that you need to escape the period. Otherwise, the regex treats the period as a match to any character. To match just that pattern, you can use something like:

```
re.findall('[\d]{2}X\d\.\d', 'asb12X4.4abc')
```

`[\d]{2}` matches a sequence of two integers, `X` matches the literal X, `\d` matches a single integer, `\.` matches the literal ., and `\d` matches the final integer.

This will match and return only `12X4.4`.

It sounds like you instead want to remove everything *after* the matched expression. To get your desired output, you can do something like:

```
re.split('(.*?[\d]{2}X\d\.\d)', 'some random words 21X2.5  Some more words')[1]
```

which will return `some random words 21X2.5`. This expression pulls everything before and including the matched regex and returns it, discarding the end.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks Jason! worked like a charm - I wasn't sure about the regex.

Answer (score 2):

Use following regex:

```
re.search("(.*?\d\dX\d\.\d)", "some random words 21X2.5 Some more words").groups()[0]
```

Output:

```
'some random words 21X2.5'
```

Comment: Instead of `groups()[0]` you could use `group()`, and the parentheses are not needed in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

To remove everything **after** the pattern, i.e do exactly as you say...:

```
s = re.sub(r'(\d\dX\d\.\d).*', r'\1', s)
```

Of course, if you mean something else than what you said, something different will be needed!  E.g if you want to also remove the pattern itself, not just (as you said) what's **after** it:

```
s = re.sub(r'\d\dX\d\.\d.*', r'', s)
```

and so forth, depending on what, exactly, *are* your specs!-)